# "$ is not defined" from JSNI; jquery already present

Tags: gwt, zurb-foundation, jsni

I'm attempting to use Zurb Foundation with GWT. Foundation javascript widgets need to be initialized after they are rendered; because I'm using a "single page" approach, I need to call the foundation initialization method after rendering new content.

Their docs show this as:

```
<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

...which should be placed at the end of a page.

I made a JSNI method that calls this same function:

```
public static native void foundationInit() /*-{
    $(document).foundation();
}-*/;
```

However, when this is called, I get an error in the javascript console: "$ is not defined". This is confusing because $ is most definitely defined; jquery is loaded, and in the javascript console I can type "$(document).foundation()" to run the function. So what's the issue?

Comment: It may not be defined at the time you're calling it.  Sometimes the console can mislead you, because all the page's resources are loaded by the time you do things in the console.

Comment: Don't you need to refer to it as `$wnd.$`?

Comment: @SurrealDreams good point, but not the case here -- I'm loading jquery  when the app first initializes, and then making this call after the user initializes.

Comment: @ChrisMartin thanks, you got me to a working solution:

$wnd.jQuery($doc).foundation()

If you want to post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to refer to the jQuery object `$` as `$wnd.$`.

> When accessing the browser's window and document objects from JSNI, you must reference them as $wnd and $doc, respectively. Your compiled script runs in a nested frame, and $wnd and $doc are automatically initialized to correctly refer to the host page's window and document.

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html